# How to get Russian works in Fcitx?

Tags: fcitx

Mozc works properly as expected but however i can't manage to set Russian works as same from fcitx-configtool.
When i input, there's only English alphabet instead of Russian.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `System Configuration`-> `Change Input Source` not works for me, but use `fcitx configuration` util helps.

Answer (score 0):

As a Russian learner, I encountered the same problem today after switching from ibus to fcitx.  I googled and find this question.  However I found the solution myself and share here.

It seemed to me this is a bug in fcitx.  After switching to Russian keyword layout, the keyboard does not take effect immediately and it only takes effect the second time you enter the app.  I just switch focus to other app and back the original app (by pressing and releasing alt-tab twice) where I want to type Russian.

The same problem does not occur when switching from English to other CJK input method.